# How does High Cohesion help us reduce Coupling?

Tags: oop, coupling, design-principles, cohesion

Assume methods `M1` and `M2`  have strongly related responsibilities

*First example:*

**If**

• `M1` and `M2` are defined within class `A` ( thus class `A` is highly cohesive )

• class `B` uses `A.M1` and class `C` uses `A.M2`

**then**

• `A` is coupled with both `B` and `C` classes

• changing the signature of  `M1` will require changes only in `B`, but not in `C`

*Second example:*

**If**

• `M1` is defined within class `A1` ( thus `B` is coupled with `A1` )

• `M2` is defined withing class `A2` ( thus `C` is coupled with `A2` )

**then**

• changing the signature of `M1` will require changes only in `B`, but not in `C`

a) To my understanding, classes in last example are no more coupled than classes in first example! Or am I missing something?

b) As far as I can tell, classes in first example are more loosely coupled than those in second example only if:

- we assume that changing the signature of `M1` will also require us to change the signature of `M2`, but I don't see that happening very often?!
- or if both `M1` and `M2` operate on the data of same type T1, then replacing T1 with T2 will require changes in both `M1` and `M2`?!
- or if we assume that due to `M1` and `M2` having closely related responsibilities, that the chances are that much greater that changing `M1` will often require `M2` also to be changed (even if `M1` doesn't directly or indirectly call `M2`)?!
- or if we assume that due to `M1` and `M2` having closely related responsibilities, the chances are much greater that some class will require both `M1` and `M2` ( as such having `M1` and `M2` in single class reduces coupling )?!

c) Are there any other reasons why defining `M1` and `M2` within `A` ( instead of defining `M1` within `A1` and `M2` within `A2` ) will reduce coupling?

Note - I'm aware that we should have higly cohesive modules due to easier maintenance and reusability

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. What you are missing that is if ClassA is cohesive, changing M1 will cause ClassB to access some other method in ClassA. It increases maintenance because you won't have to modify other modules (method and variables) in ClassA itself.

When we call a class cohesive (say ClassA) , we mean that we can easily use the purpose(s) of the class without have to make our caller class (ClassB) according to the requirements of ClassA. Hence, ClassB is not dependent on ClassA and thereby cohesion is reduced.

Don't think of think of cohesion in terms of methods. Methods are not called cohesive, classes are.

Comment: "...changing M1 will cause ClassB to access some other method in ClassA" I'm not following you. Why would changing M1 cause class B to access some other method in class A?

Comment: that's because A is highly cohesive (rather, if A is highly cohesive, all this will b true

Comment: "...all this will b true" You mean all assumptions I made under b) are true if A is highly cohesive?